# How can I place a number X in Column C(if cell is empty) where X is equal to the same row in column B minus 1?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns that just have numbers in them. Every cell in column B has a number. Only certain cells in column C have a number.

I want to go down every cell in column C, check if it's empty, and if it is empty, place the adjacent column B's number minus 1 into C.

[In this picture, the left two columns would be the input and the right two columns would be the desired result after the script is run(without putting it into new columns).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFYUZ.png)

The B minus 1 part is the part I am having trouble with.

````
For Each cell In Range("C1:C20")
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
        
        cell = `....`
        
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell


End If
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Offset`, and remove the `Exit For`:

```
For Each cell In Range("C1:C20")
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        cell.Value = cell.Offset(,-1).Value - 1
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: This does work in my example workbook, However, I am having a separate issue now that I did not describe in the question(my bad). My numbers in column B are the result of the COUNTA formula. So When I try to get the Value of that cell it gives a 'runtime error 13 mismatch'. Is there a way I can just get the integer from that cell? I'm assuming '.Value' is resolved as the contents of the cell, which is a formula, so it can't do a subtract on it(obviously)

Comment: What is your exact formula? The `.Value` of the cell is independent of whether it's a formula. If you're getting a type mismatch, then the value in column B is not numeric.

Comment: =COUNTA($B$7:B9) + 1

The result of that formula is a number for every cell in that column. If the .Value works like that, then I'm not sure how I would be getting a type mismatch error

Comment: Maybe `Debug.Print cell.Address, cell.Value` and see which cell it is / what the value is.

Comment: So I'm messing around in the debugger and it looks like it actually is a string...which would be why.